# Most efficient way of initializing a map of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, c++17

What's the most efficient way to initialize a map of vectors of fixed size set to the same value except for the first one?

So for example assume it's a map of strings to a vector of booleans:

`std::map<std::string, std::vector<bool>> map;`

I can think of two ways:

```
for (const std::string& key : {"key1", "key2", "key3"}) {
  map[key] = std::vector<bool>(10, false); // Initialize to length of 10 and set all to false
  map[key][0] = true;  
}
```

vs

```
for (const std::string& key : {"key1", "key2", "key3"}) {
  std::vector<bool>& vec = map[key]; // Default initialization to empty vector
  vec.insert(vec.begin(), 10, false); // insert 10 elements 
  vec[0] = true;  
}
```

The second avoids a double lookup but requires more lines of code and an extra vector initialization. Is there a more concise way than the two above?

Comment: Unrelated: `std::vector<bool>` can be implemented as a packed bit array to save space. This makes `vector<bool>` a bit different from a regular `vector` and can trip you up if you aren't expecting it. [Docs for `vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) so you can see if it's gonna get ya before it does.

Comment: Note that the code you wrote is just a description of what you want done.  The actual code generated by the compiler after optimization is used may look far different than what you've written.  You should look at the code generation after optimizations, rather than assuming that the number of lines of code or number of variables declared leads to efficient code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a temp `vector<bool>`:

```
std::vector<bool> vb(10, false);
vb[0] = true;
for (const std::string& key : {"key1", "key2", "key3"})
  map[key] = b;
```

Note that your original code used `k` where you should have been using `key`

Comment: Why not use `try_emplace` to avoid extra initializations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that's quite concise:

```
std::vector<bool> vb(10, false);
vb[0] = true;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<bool>> map{{"key1", vb},{"key2", vb},{"key3", vb}};
```